# "bluetooth not found. plugin dongle" in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: bluetooth, blueman

my laptop is dell latitude E5430. i just downloaded ubuntu 20.04. i uninstalled windows and installed ubuntu while booting. i even downloaded blueman bluetooth manager. in windows, it used to work pretty well. but in linux, iam not able to open the bluetooth manager.

Answer (score 0):

i had similar issue with wifi - at settings there is a switch on upper right corner (app's statusbar), you should be able to enable BT in this way. if it doesn't work - install synaptic manager and check for updates. if there are updates - do it, maybe drivers for your network card will update and then bluetooth might start work. if you don't have any - find your drivers and reinstall them. hope it helps ;)